# How to make a browser open local file, not download it?

Tags: html, linux, browser, local

I'm trying to make an html page where user can see a list of movies and start watching them. The page is supposed to work locally on one particular machine (`file` protocol, or `http://localhost` if needed).

The thing is with "start watching them" part. If I do it straightforward way (`<a href="path/to/movie.mkv">watch it</a>`) it asks where to save the file.

I'd like it to start `vlc` or file manager with corresponding directory open.

I was thinking about creating dummy files with some non-standard extensions, associating them with custom MIME type and `.desktop` file. The `.desktop` file was supposed to start corresponding movie. But I've got little or no experience with it, and it still have to download it first, doesn't it?

Preferable browsers are `chrome` or `firefox`. Target OS is `linux`.

**UPD** Judging from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18246357/52499) what I want seems to be impossible. There's probably a workaround I mentioned above, to make browser download a "shortcut" (containing path to a movie), rather then the whole movie, and associate this custom file type with a `.desktop` file, which would start corresponding movie. Additionally, make the browser auto-save downloads and auto-open files of this type. But not sure if I'm going this way.

Comment: On Windows there is a VLC integration plugin with some codec packs, so the video starts streaming immediately. You should take a look if there is something like that for Linux.

Comment: @mrmut Can you tell me which exactly plugin you're talking about?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to launch browser to open local file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22535148/how-to-open-local-file-in-browser) and a host of other similar answers found on SO.

Comment: @Rob Are you sure your link has anything to do with my question? I'm not going to write an android application.

Comment: @x-yuri I clicked on the wrong link but changed it. Even still, you should search SO for your answer first.

Comment: @x-yuri You can check it here: https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:WebPlugin/

Comment: @Rob Please change both links, one in the comment and one in the question. Additionally, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18246053/how-can-i-create-a-link-to-a-local-file-on-a-locally-run-web-page) seems like a better suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After all, I ended up doing it "custom mime type" way. First, I failed to make `chromium` play `mkv` files. Second, I believe that browser is not for watching movies (although you can).

So, I'm gonna use `chromium` here. Go to `Settings`. Scroll to the bottom of the page. Click `Show advanced settings...`:

[image: chromium/Settings/Show advanced settings... link]

Scroll until `Downloads` section:

[image: chromium/Settings/Downloads section]

*(optional)* Uncheck `Ask where to save each file before downloading`. Create file `my-movie.movie-shortcut`, containing:

```
path/to/my/movie.mkv
```

Create and open a page containing link to this file. (You most likely have to serve the page using a web server, or else `chromium` will just open the file itself after figuring out it's of `text/plain` mime type.) Click the link, download the file, and *(optional)* check `Always open files of this type` menu item:

[image: chromium/Always open files of this type menu item]

Now then, `chromium` most likely runs `xdg-open path/to/file` to open files. At least, if you make `xdg-open` work, it will work in `chromium` as well.

First, you need to install `mimetype`. If not installed, `xdg-open` uses `file` to determine mime type. And I doubt `file` can be configured to return custom mime type.

Then add a line to `/usr/share/mime/globs`:

```
text/x-movie-shortcut:*.movie-shortcut
```

Do note, `/usr/share/mime/globs` is autogenerated, so make sure to do it the proper way if need be.

Then add a line to `~/.config/mimeapps.list` to `[Default Applications]` section:

```
text/x-movie-shortcut=run-movie.desktop
```

And create `~/.local/share/applications/run-movie.desktop`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Run Movie
GenericName=Run Movie
Comment=Run Movie
Exec=/home/yuri/bin/run-movie.sh
Icon=vlc
Terminal=false
Type=Application
MimeType=text/x-movie-shortcut
```

And create `~/bin/run-movie.sh` (you can probably try to put the command into the `.desktop` file):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -eu
/usr/bin/vlc --started-from-file "$(cat "$1")"
```

I'm running Arch Linux, so your mileage may vary. Here's supposedly [useful link](https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/mime-types-custom.html.en) for at least `xfce`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to embed the video in the web page:

```
<video width="x" height="y" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not support the video tag.<!--error message for outdated browsers-->
</video>
```

Comment: I used "movie.mp4" because most browsers support mp4. You can use "movie.mkv" as well but some browsers may not support it. Chrome does - I'm unsure about other browsers.

Comment: I'd like to avoid that if possible. Having it run in a standalone application makes for a better user experience, I think.

Comment: Then you might have to use the <embed> tag instead. <embed src="movie.mp4" width="x" height="y" autostart="false" loop="false" />. But the user will need to have a player that is able to play the particular video format installed.