# Loading HTML and CSS file on local browser

Tags: html, css, web, localhost

I'm very new to coding and web development. I'm working with HTML and CSS at the moment. The trouble is, I can't see what I'm coding.

**How do you load a HTML and CSS file onto a local host so that you can see what you are doing?**

Really appreciate it if you could give your input. :)

Comment: just open the html file using your browser.....

Comment: pls provide your code watever u have done.

Comment: You just need to open you html using some browser

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open local file in browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22535148/how-to-open-local-file-in-browser)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) And the perfect question And how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) SO is not a free Coding or Code Conversion or Debugging or Tutorial or Library Finding service Here at SO we fix your attempts, we do not code things for you

Comment: Open the HTML file in browser, open developers tool, go to source tab, and check the files.

Comment: @Matt what is the problem? `I can't see what I'm coding.` what do you mean by this

Answer (score 2):

I've had this question as well, haha. But you'll learn.

So there are *two* solutions here; one using a `localhost` and one just simply viewing the file.

I'm not sure what device you're on, but to view your file, just simply double click it as you would do to open any other file. Then you will be able to see your code and what you're programming.

The second solution is the use of a `localhost`; it's basically a test environment for your website to view it during development.

To set up a `localhost` on a Macintosh device, you simply go to the *Finder* and search for *Terminal*, later open it and write; `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`.

If you have a folder for your files as well (which is recommended for future reference), just use `cd` and type where it is. The easiest method would be placing it on the *Desktop*, and then write in the *Terminal*; `cd Desktop` -> `cd the-folder-you-have-your-code-in` and then write `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`.

To access this server, just type `localhost` in the search bar where you'd search for items on the web.

Hope this helps you, and welcome to the developing society!

---

For future reference, when you become a full-fledged developer, don't use `Homestead/Laravel`, it's a pain in the ass when you don't understand it. Use WAMP, MAMP, or XAMPP based on what device you're on.

Comment: This is the best answer for newbies! I was just practising some html and css (i am a back end dev-noob), and generally i set up a create -react-app, but this is much simpler and the only thing remains is hot-reloading, which i'll be doing soon . Cheers!  For linux folks> command is - python3 -m http.server

Answer (score 0):

Just open the html file with your browser.  On Windows, in Windows Explorer right click on the file and choose open with, then choose your browser.

Comment: if there are only sentences in the answer then make a comment rather than answer.

Comment: @BhavinShah answer can be one liner too.. Its only non answers like `suggestions`, `try this` , `may be` kind of answers that are not encouraged

Answer (score 0):

file:///[complete path to your file] does the trick in Chrome, Firefox and IE, but as @Atrix said, right click + open in [your favourite browser] works too.

You might want to install a full-fledged webserver one day or another though, like [Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/) or [nginx](http://nginx.org/). You also have full stacks servers available (usually coming with a PHP interpreter and a database server), like [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) (on Windows), or [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) (on Windows, Linux and MacOS)

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

On a Window machine at the prompt type **start** *the-HTML-file-name*

Answer (score 0):

Here is an efficient alternative:

Go to [W3Schools Tryit Editor](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_basic). Wait for the page to fully load. Then enter the following line in the browser's console and press Enter:

```
document.getElementById('textareawrapper').setAttribute("onkeup","submitTryit(1)")
```

Now start typing your code in the text area. This is far better than working with a text editor as it shows the output directly as you type.